# Segmentation fault when enabling optimization in a simple GTK+ application?

Tags: c, null, 64-bit, segmentation-fault, gtk

Might be that it is too late, but I find it at least curious that the following few lines seem to be causing a segmentation fault if and only when compiled with gcc's optimization, even "-O1"!

```
settings_dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons("gatotray Settings"
    , NULL, 0, GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, FALSE, GTK_STOCK_SAVE, TRUE, 0);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(settings_dialog), "response", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(settings_dialog), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(settings_destroyed), NULL);
GtkWidget *vb = gtk_dialog_get_content_area(GTK_DIALOG(settings_dialog));
GtkWidget *hb = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 3);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(hb), gtk_label_new("Background:"));
GtkWidget *cb = gtk_color_button_new();
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(hb), cb);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vb), hb);
```

This is the backtrace:

```
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  0x00007ffff4d88052 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff5304112 in g_strdup () from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff5bc799d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff5ba826c in g_object_new_valist ()
   from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff5ba84f1 in g_object_new () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff78502d5 in gtk_button_new_from_stock ()
   from /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff787cc95 in gtk_dialog_add_button ()
   from /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff787cd60 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff787cf60 in gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons ()
   from /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#9  0x0000000000402bb9 in show_settings_dialog () at settings.c:24
#10 0x0000000000403328 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2b8) at gatotray.c:286
```

... settings.c:24 is exactly the first line listed above, seems like "gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons" is the culprit...

Versions:
gcc: 4.4.3
GTK+: 2.20.1

BTW, forgot to mention that commenting out certain lines *after* the conflictive call prevents it from happening. Particularly the line with "gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(hb), cb);"

I tried almost all suitable combinations of GtkTypes/GTK_MACROS, it makes no difference.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you compile?

Comment: No warnings, of course! :-)
With "gcc -c ``pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0``  -std=c99 -Wall -O1 -ggdb"
->

Comment: Meanwhile, I found that adding an extra 0 to the variable argument list of gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons() seems to solve the issue, even when it does not correspond to its documentation. I will answer it myself if we don't get a more authoritative explanation about va_args, optimization, and/or this specific issue :-P.

Comment: GTK has noutriously poor documentation. Even so, you don't appear to be following it, try passing NULL as the last parameter, this will certainly be the problem if you are on 64bit and not 32 bit.

Comment: I would recommend to run the program under Valgrind, it may give you some insight. You may also want to see the code generated by the preprocessor (gcc -E).

Comment: I think Myforwik has it right, 0 is not the same as NULL if you're in a variable argument list (and on 64-bit).

Comment: Indeed! 0 is not the same as NULL in 64 bits!!! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short: use **NULL** when the manual says **NULL**, and not a plain **0**!

*(Since I can't choose the comments as an answer, I am writing the answer myself, giving credit to the helpful comments...)*

GTK+ documentation states this:

```
GtkWidget*
gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons (const gchar    *title,
                             GtkWindow      *parent,
                             GtkDialogFlags  flags,
                             const gchar    *first_button_text,
                         ...);

title : Title of the dialog, or NULL. allow-none.
parent : Transient parent of the dialog, or NULL. allow-none.
flags : from GtkDialogFlags
first_button_text : stock ID or text to go in first button, or NULL. allow-none.
... : response ID for first button, then additional buttons, ending with NULL
```

But I was lazy that night and typed just a '0' where the NULL was expected:

```
settings_dialog = GTK_DIALOG(gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons("gatotray Settings"
    , NULL, 0, GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, FALSE, GTK_STOCK_SAVE, TRUE, 0));
```

... Not noticing that NULL is a pointer which in my 64-bits system is 64-bits wide, whereas 0 is a 32-bit integer...

Also, seems like in the variable argument list the compiler was not able to detect the inconsistency: the code compiled quietly with -Wall.

As [Myforwik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70189/myforwik) suggested and [Havoc P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277156/havoc-p) further clarified, using 'NULL' there instead of the '0' fixed the issue. Thanks guys!

For the record, I did a test compiling in 32 bits mode where NULL is also 32-bits, and in that case there was no segfault. It is still incorrect though, since the documentation is clear enough, and NULL is not 0, no matter what the C++ committeemen ever say! ;-)

Comment: The key *gotcha* here is the variable argument list - a C compiler will transform any literal `0` into a `NULL` pointer **when it knows** you need a pointer — and it can't (necessarily) know that when compiling a varargs invocation!